# Audio Stuttering in version 22.04.1

Tags: sound, virtualbox

So for starters I have Ubuntu running on a virtual machine and everytime I watch a YouTube video in it the video and audio Stuttering just about every second. I am new to Linux AND virtual machines if that matters.

Comment: If the VM and or the host does not have enough power that can happen. Any other apps having any issues? I assume you are using a browser, have you tried a different browser?

Comment: This question notoriously lacks any meaningful actionable information. Please [edit] and add the host OS version, the guest OS release/version, the virtualization software you're running (and whether or not extensions pack and guest additions were installed whenever applicable) ans well as hardware specifications (real hardware) and the resources assigned to the VM.